# reuse the inflated view in android

Tags: android, android-layout

The following piece of code is inflating the same view for 20 times. Since inflating is costly. I want to inflate it only one, and use the same view for 20 items, i just want to change the visible data in the UI.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context); 
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), parent, false);
    itemView.setText(data.getName(i);
    ll.add(itemView);
}
```

I want something like this.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context); 
View itemView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), parent, false);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    itemView.setText(data.getName(i);
    ll.add(itemView);
}
```

But am not able to use the itemView obj this way.

Can anyone tell me how to use the view many times once it inflated.

Comment: if you have only a textView in your layout then you can create textView programmatically

Comment: You are creating 20 different views from the same xml. Not possible to make less than 20 views if you need 20 views.

Comment: textview i gave for an example, i have few more views.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. If you think its costly then find another way to create your layout.

But consider gridViews for example. They create a ton of views and show them and that works great.

You cannot add the same object of a view 2 times to a layout. Every object has its own state which in your case in a way says that you will share the state between all your 20 views which doesn't make sense to do, meaning changing the text on one textView will change it on all the rest...

Just inflate 20 seperate views and fill them appropriately.

Also consider using ListView or GridView if you actually have the exact same view it can offer some nice features like view recycling.

Answer (score -1):

You should use ViewHolder patern:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

it should do all things You want

Comment: I want to add this 20 views to Horizontal Scroll view. List View has adapter which will provide reusable convert view.  Whether Horizontal Scroll view also has any adapter which will provide data.?

Comment: Viewholder doesnt clone views. Make code to clone the view before add to layout

Comment: viewholder is just a pattern to work with ListView, original question implies that ListView is not an option